# Count total of subarrays with certain values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
$example = 
  array
    'test' =>
      array(
        'something' => 'value'
      ),
    'whatever' =>
      array(
        'something' => 'other'
      ),
    'blah' =>
      array(
        'something' => 'other'
      )
  );
```

I want to count how many of `$example`'s subarrays contain an element with the value `other`.

What's the easiest way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is what you need:

```
count(array_filter($example, function($element){

    return $element['something'] == 'other';

}));
```

In case you want to be more flexible:

```
$key = 'something';
$value = 'other';

$c = count(array_filter($example, function($element) use($key, $value){

    return $element[$key] == $value;

}));
```

Comment: This one works for me "as is", but when I try to replace "other" with a variable, it just gives me a result of 0  :/

Comment: This is because the lambda function is not aware of your variable - see my edit in case you want to use a var.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
$count = 0;
foreach( $example as $value ) {
    if( in_array("other", $value ) )
        $count++;
}
```