# Count total number of subarrays with certain value where value is a variable

Tags: php, arrays, count

I'm trying to use the code from answer to this question: [Count values in subarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232960/count-total-of-subarrays-with-certain-values-in-php)

But it doesn't want to work with variables?

So for instance, this works:

```
echo count(array_filter($tasks, function($element){
    return $element['parent'] == 15;
}));
```

> Echoes out: 4

But this fails:

```
$number = 15;

//Kolla ifall denna har subtasks?
echo count(array_filter($tasks, function($element) {
    return $element['parent'] == $number;
}));
```

> Echoes out 0

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Same question as always: what does "fail" mean?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$number` is not available inside the lambda function, add `use ($number)`:

```
$number = 15;
//Kolla ifall denna har subtasks?
echo count(array_filter($tasks, function($element) use ($number) {
return $element['parent'] == $number;
}));
```

Comment: You might also want to consider handing the variable `$number` over as a function argument. That makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: I don't think `array_filter()` can do that and I don't think that it will make it any easier either. For PHP 5.2 there is an ugly workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482989/php-array-filter-with-arguments