# How to find number of inbound links in php if i have array of linking between pages?

Tags: php, array-filter, inbound

I have this 2d array that represent outgoing links of each page returned by search engine, now I have to find number of inbound links of each page.

eg 1 is present in sub array in key2,3,4,5,6 so its number of inbound will be 5.

I need this in PHP.

```
$links = array( 
        1 => array(2,3,4,5,6),
        2 => array(1,3,4,5,6),
        3 => array(1,2,4,5,6),
        4 => array(1,2,3,5,6),
        5 => array(1,2,3,4,6),
        6 => array(1,2,3,4,5),
        7=> array (11),
        8=>array(7,9),
        9=> array(7),
        10=> array(8),
        11=> array(8,10),

);
```

Comment: It might be easier to help if you could show us what you want the output to be.  Could you please edit your question to include an example of the result you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12232970/689579 ?

Comment: @EricRenouf for eg for above array                 number of inbound links for 1 will be 5 ,as 1 is present in subarray at location 2,3,4,5,6

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count total of subarrays with certain values in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232960/count-total-of-subarrays-with-certain-values-in-php)

Comment: Then I think Sean is right, his link likely is your answer

Comment: i have to dynamically calculate the number of keys in which 1st key is present similarly  the number of keys in which 2nd key is present and so on

Comment: so you want all results, not just the `1` value?

Comment: yess i want duplicate count for all the keys

Answer (score 1):

probably a cleaner way, but one way is to create a new array, loop over your existing array, and add to the new array using the value as the key.

```
$results=array();
foreach($links as $link){
    foreach($link as $value){
        $results[$value] = isset($results[$value]) ? $results[$value]+1 : 1;
    }
}
```

with your example data, your results would look like -

```
Array ( 
    [1] => 5 
    [2] => 5 
    [3] => 5 
    [4] => 5 
    [5] => 5 
    [6] => 5 
    [7] => 2 
    [8] => 2 
    [9] => 1 
    [10] => 1 
    [11] => 1
)
```

Comment: bt it is not counting for key 1

Comment: what do you mean? You said `1 is present in sub array in key2,3,4,5,6 so its number of inbound will be 5` and in my example `[1] => 5`. How is `it is not counting for key 1`?

Comment: `2` is in `1,3,4,5,6` so `[2] => 5`, .... , `7` is in `8,9` so `[7] => 2`, .... , and `11` is in `7` so `[11] => 1`